# HMACSHA1 from C# To PHP

Tags: c#, php, .net, hmacsha1

I am trying to understand these line of code from C# (.Net) method to create a signature. However, I would like to do the same in PHP but not quite understand what it does in C#.

I wonder if any .net developer out there can help me to interpret the code below in 'English'?

Many thanks

```
HMAC hasher;

            Byte[] utf8EncodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", MethodName, TimeStamp, AccessID));

            hasher = HMACSHA1.Create();

            hasher.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AccessKey);

            Byte[] hashResult = hasher.ComputeHash(utf8EncodedString);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashResult);
```

Here is my PHP code. Is this correct?

> $signatureString = $methodName.':'.$timeStamp.':'.$accessID;
>   return hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureString, $accessKey, false);

Update: 30-05-2012

Just got it to work now

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureString, $accessKey,true));
```

Comment: Which parts cause your problems? Can you post your php code?

Comment: Please find my PHP example code above. Not sure if the $signatureString is correct !

Comment: I believe that's what you want, assuming you've appropriately set $accessKey, $methodName, $timeStamp and $accessID earlier in your code.  I don't exactly know what you get when you set raw_output to false, if it's not properly encoded you can always use base64encode().

Comment: I'd add base64_encode() after hash_hmac()

Comment: Brilliant. Looks like I only need to do a bit more: return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $signatureString, $accessKey, false));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer on php.net for you http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-hmac.php#105099